# Update the timestamp on a polymorphic association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have a Photo model that can belong to two other models and this is captured through a polymorphic association:

```
has_many :photos, :as => photo_container
```

I would like to update the timestamp of the photo_container models when a new photo is created. I am doing this with an after_create callback in the Photo model:

```
self.photo_container.update_attribute(:updated_at, Time.now)
```

Since both my photo_container models have an update_attribute field it should be working fine, however, I am getting the following exception for the corresponding line in the callback:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Photo::PhotoContainer)
```

Of course it works fine if I check the type of photo_container, load the model and change the timestamp but it is not clean/generic. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the touch option in the [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) association. It should work fine. Something like:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true, :touch=>true
end
```

Comment: Fantastic option however, it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: You could have some problems with the models. Update your question with definition. Maybe Someone else or I could help

Comment: Ok, it works now, I did not specify that the relationship was polymorphic and somehow, since I never had to access the photo_container of the two models, I never had an issue. Glad I did since it is way cleaner to use :touch :)